# loadChildren fat arrow function

Tags: angular, lazy-loading, angular6, angular-routing

I'm wondering if there is any chance to load a lazy-loaded module with a fat arrow function instead of typing the path as string. It would be a big advantage as the code looks better and in case of refactor the IDE can change the path of import automatically. I have seen this approach at some websites but I didn't manage to get it working, as error `Cannot read property 'loadChildren' of undefined` appears.

*Example:*

`loadChildren: () => MemberModule
--- vs ---
loadChildren: './modules/member/member.module#MemberModule'`

Comment: Its not parsing it probably.. Can you create a stackblitz of your code?

Comment: @Krishna I tried but stackblitz is not cooperating with me, anyway on stackblitz the fat arrow in loadChildren is working fine

Comment: Add some code snippets here...